# Modifying Array Formatting

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, formatting

(sorry I posted a very similar question earlier, but it looks like my original question was a little bit off)

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({                                      
      url: 'receive-country.php',    //the script to call to get data
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
            var inputArray = data;
            alert(data);
            var test_data = {"af":16.63,"al":11.58,"dz":158.97};
            jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
                map: 'world_en',
                backgroundColor: null,
                color: '#ffffff',
                hoverColor: '#eeeeee',
                hoverOpacity: null,
                selectedColor: '#dddddd',
                values: test_data,
                enableZoom: true,
                showTooltip: true,
                scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#006491'],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            });
      }
    });
```

I am receiving via Ajax some `data` that I want to display on my jQuery map `#vmap`.  I created some `test_data` that works great with the map, but I can't seem to get `data` in the same format as `test_data`.

I'm not sure exactly what array formatting `data` is in, but when I alert it, it comes out as:

```
US,7,US,9,US,10
```

How can I change the formatting?

---

Here is the PHP page that sends the JSON data:

```
$country_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM happiness ORDER BY id ASC");
  $country_array = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($country_result)) {
    $country_array[] = array($row[4], $row[2]);
  }

  echo json_encode($country_array);
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is a screenshot of the console-log.  I'm not sure how to read it exactly.
[image]

Comment: Use `console.log` instead of alert and you will see the data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the PHP `data` is most likely a two-dimensional array looking like this:

```
[[US,7],[US,9],[US,10]]
```

You could convert it into the other format this way:

```
var newData = {};
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  newData[data[i][0]] = data[i][1];
}
```

EDIT: as other answers suggest, the thing to do is obviously to fix the PHP-side of the problem, not to work around it on the javascript side. I'm leaving my answer as it may add some value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get `key -> value` pairs. So, in PHP change the line

```
$country_array[] = array($row[4], $row[2]);
```

with

```
$country_array[$row[4]] = $row[2];
```

I guess, because you are appending to an array in PHP, actual data you get in JavaScript is `['US', 7, 'US', 9, 'US', 10]`, not `['US':7, 'US':9, 'US':10]` as you probably expected.

## EDIT

Now I see your update. Anyway, you get array of arrays instead array of key-value pairs (which is very standard and common in JavaScript). Try as I suggested.

Comment: He is appending arrays to an array, making a two-dimensional array, which his newly added console output seems to confirm.

Comment: I saw lately and accordingly edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP page the line

```
$country_array[] = array($row[4], $row[2]);
```

should be

```
 $country_array[] = array($row[4] => $row[2]);
```

This will make your PHP array associative, which will be json_encoded to a Javascript object instead of the Javascript array you are currently seeing.